# Does V4L2 driver support Raw Bayer capture with HQ camera?

Tags: camera, driver, v4l2

I was under impression that current V4L2 driver supports raw capture, but:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl --list-formats
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'YU12' (Planar YUV 4:2:0)
    [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
    [2]: 'RGB3' (24-bit RGB 8-8-8)
    [3]: 'JPEG' (JFIF JPEG, compressed)
    [4]: 'H264' (H.264, compressed)
    [5]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
    [6]: 'YVYU' (YVYU 4:2:2)
    [7]: 'VYUY' (VYUY 4:2:2)
    [8]: 'UYVY' (UYVY 4:2:2)
    [9]: 'NV12' (Y/CbCr 4:2:0)
    [10]: 'BGR3' (24-bit BGR 8-8-8)
    [11]: 'YV12' (Planar YVU 4:2:0)
    [12]: 'NV21' (Y/CrCb 4:2:0)
    [13]: 'RX24' (32-bit XBGR 8-8-8-8)
```

doesn't show any Raw Bayer formats. I'm using Raspberry Pi 4, HQ camera and `2021-05-07-raspios-buster-armhf-full`. Am I missing something?

Comment: there are two differente drivers, one is the isp driver that indeed supports only non-raw formats. But there is also the unicam driver that support only raw formats.

Comment: @dafnahaktana How do I use or test the unicam driver? Does it have V4L2 API? Can I switch between isp and unicam drivers? I don't see an explanation at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/accessories/camera.html#camera-serial-interface-2-csi2-unicam

Comment: It does have v4l2 api, but it will be exposed only if the camera driver (imx219/ ov5647) was binded. see https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.10.y/drivers/media/platform/bcm2835/bcm2835-unicam.c#L2538